# stuck in pandas if loop all() any()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I try to write some basic functions and found me know completely stuck in a quite simple problem regarding the use of if elif else on python pandas dataframe. Here is an example:
dummy data:

```
d = {'x': [1, 2, 0, -2, -2], 'y': [3, 4, 5, 4, -4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

my function:

```
def cart2sph(data):  #ceval indicates using numerical expressions
    newDF = pd.DataFrame()
    x = data['x'].astype(float)
    y = data['y'].astype(float)
    if (x == 0).all():
      newDF['angle'] = sign(y)* pi / 2
    else:
      newDF['angle'] = arctan(y/x)
    if (x < 0 and y >= 0).all():
      newDF['angle'] += pi
    elif (x < 0 and y < 0).all():
      newDF['angle'] -= pi
    return newDF
```

I always get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in cart2sph
  File "C:\Users\tpotrusil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 955, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

...and can´t see the problem!?!

Very thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always post the full error message - it contains valuable information, where exactly the problem occurs. And I would add the keyword `pandas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are misunderstanding what `.all()` does. Your second `if` statement (and the following `elif`) can only be true if *all* values in the `x` column are strictly negative. Given that you are calculating angles from the origin for each point, you actually want to consider each row separately.

I think you're looking for something like the following, which applies your angle formula to each row, not the entire dataframe.

```
def cart2sph(row):
    ''' Called on each (x, y) row of the dataframe. '''
    x, y = row[['x', 'y']]
    if x == 0:
        angle = sign(y)* pi / 2
    else:
        angle = arctan(y/x)
    if (x < 0) & (y >= 0):
        angle += pi
    elif (x < 0) & (y < 0):
        angle -= pi
    return angle

angles = df.apply(cart2sph, axis=1)
```

There is also a faster way to do this by vectorisation, which should give better performance if your dataframe is large:

```
# Split the x==0/x!=0 cases and recombine (vectorises the first if statement)
angles = pd.concat([
    arctan(df.y / df.x)[df.x != 0],
    (sign(df.y) * pi / 2)[df.x == 0]]).sort_index()

# Add/subtract for specific cases (vectorises the second if statement)
angles[(df.x < 0) & (df.y >= 0)] += pi
angles[(df.x < 0) & (df.y < 0)] -= pi
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and also for the vectorized approach - I can use this quite often!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace 
`(x < 0 and y >= 0).all()`
by
`(x < 0).all() and (y >= 0).all()`

Comment: thanks for your help! I do not get the above described error when using your suggestion, but the second if-loop is never touched: The function works fine for the first three values in x-column which are covered by the first if-else-loop. Value number 4 and 5 should be modified in the second if-elif-loop before returned - but this second loop is not reached! I´m not sure what´s wrong here??